# Deploy jar file with parameters on Heroku

Tags: heroku

I am trying to deploy a jar file on Heroku that receives two parameters.

For this I do the following:

```
heroku create appname
heroku deploy:jar rest/target/rest-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

But I get an error saying that the parameters are not specified:

```
app [web.1]: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
app [web.1]: at org.dbpedia.spotlight.web.rest.Server.main (Server.java:86)
```

[image]

The original jar runs as follows:

```
java -jar rest-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar es http://localhost:2222/rest/
```

The first parameter is a folder and the second is the listening address of the REST service.

I would appreciate if anyone knows how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the directory you are deploying from, create a file named "Procfile" with the start line prefixed by "web:" e.g.

web: java -jar rest-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar es "http://localhost:2222/rest/"

Look into the https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile